# Storing Multiple responses in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file **main.txt**

```
{
    "a": "2014T00+0000",
    "max": 6924,
    "maxi": 86924,
    "rP": 0,
    "rPS": 100,
    "rT": 372,
    "res": [
        {
            "aDV": 11,
            "aVs": 2,
            "acc": null,
            "as": null,
            "cs": [],
            "mP": [
                {
                    "len": 2,
                    "st": 5,
                    "txt": "adas"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "aDV": 112,
            "aVs": 23,
            "acc": null,
            "as": null,
            "cs": [],
            "mP": [
                {
                    "len": 22,
                    "st": 51,
                    "txt": "adasA"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "sD": "2014-04-01T00:00:00.000+0000"
}
```

I want to store each response in a separate dictionary separated by ":" . Full Response is in this `("res"[{response 1},{response 2},......{response n}],)` format. Individual response format is like this `({"a":b},)`. Above file contains 2 responses `(res[{response1},{response2}],)`. First response needs to be stored in dictionary#1 and so on. There can be a list which can point to these dictionaries.

Any help will be good. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please arrange the indendence of the code? And could you please show what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for the indendence part, I have fixed it now and the solution is working now. The problem was I was treating the file as text file instead of json.

Comment: This doesn't affect how you paste and indendence here the document. If you found useful the answer of Mathias select them with the green tick on the left side of his answer. This will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like json (EDIT: not look like, it's valid json formatted)

```python
import json

handler = open('main.txt', 'r')
data = json.loads(handler.read())
```

Then access the data:

```python
>>> len(data['res'])
2

>>> bb['res'][0]  # First response
{u'acc': None, u'aDV': 11, u'aVs': 2, u'as': None, u'mP': [{u'txt': u'adas', u'len': 2, u'st': 5}], u'cs': []}

>>> bb['res'][1]  # Second response
{u'acc': None, u'aDV': 112, u'aVs': 23, u'as': None, u'mP': [{u'txt': u'adasA', u'len': 22, u'st': 51}], u'cs': []}
```